# PDO wrapper class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php

class Database
{
    private $_dbh;
    private $_stmt;
    private $_queryCounter = 0;

    public function __construct($user, $pass, $dbname)
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $dbname;
        //$dsn = 'sqlite:myDatabase.sq3';
        //$dsn = 'sqlite::memory:';
        $options = array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
                    );
        try {
            $this->_dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->_stmt = $this->_dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    public function bind($pos, $value, $type = null)
    {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->_stmt->bindValue($pos, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_queryCounter++;
        return $this->_stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultset()
    {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function single()
    {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    // returns last insert ID
    //!!!! if called inside a transaction, must call it before closing the transaction!!!!!!
    public function lastInsertId()
    {
        return $this->_dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    // begin transaction // must be innoDatabase table
    public function beginTransaction()
    {
        return $this->_dbh->beginTransaction();
    }

    // end transaction
    public function endTransaction()
    {
        return $this->_dbh->commit();
    }

    // cancel transaction
    public function cancelTransaction()
    {
        return $this->_dbh->rollBack();
    }

    // returns number of rows updated, deleted, or inserted
    public function rowCount()
    {
        return $this->_stmt->rowCount();
    }

    // returns number of queries executed
    public function queryCounter()
    {
        return $this->_queryCounter;
    }

    public function debugDumpParams()
    {
        return $this->_stmt->debugDumpParams();
    }

}
```

Testing the class....

```
/**
 * Establish a DB connection.
 */
$database = new Database('root', '', 'testing');


/**
 * Insert 1 new record
 */
$database->query('INSERT INTO testing (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (:name,:tag,:date)');
$database->bind(':name', 'john doe');
$database->bind(':tag', 'hi');
$database->bind(':date', 'may 1');
$database->execute();
//returns last auto increment ID
echo $database->lastInsertId();


/**
 * Insert 2 new records using Transactions
 * Also Bind new results without running $database->query() a second time
 */
$database->beginTransaction();
$database->query('INSERT INTO testing (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (:name,:tag,:date)');
$database->bind(':name', 'user 1');
$database->bind(':tag', 'hello');
$database->bind(':date', 'may 2');
$database->execute();

// Add second item to DB without runing $database->query() again
$database->bind(':name', 'user 2');
$database->bind(':tag', 'hello 2');
$database->bind(':date', 'may 22');
$database->execute();
//returns last auto increment ID
echo $database->lastInsertId();
//$database->cancelTransaction();
$database->endTransaction();


/**
 * Select a row of items from DB
 */
$database->query('SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM testing WHERE id > ? LIMIT ?');
$database->bind(1, 1);
$database->bind(2, 5);
$row = $database->single();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";


/**
 * Create a new query, bind values and return a resultset.
 */
$database->query('SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM testing WHERE col2 = :col2 LIMIT :limit');
$database->bind(':col2', 'hello 2');
$database->bind(':limit', 10);
$rs = $database->resultset();

foreach ($rs as $row) {
    echo $row['col1'] . '<br>';
    echo $row['col2'] . '<br>';
    echo $row['col3'] . '<br>';
}


/**
 * Show number of queries executed on DB
 */
echo $database->queryCounter();
?>
```

That is what I have so far. I am wanting to modify it though so I can run it more like this below instead of running the separate `bind()` methods on every item...

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO user(user_id, user_username, user_password)
        VALUES( :user_id, :user_username, :user_password))';
$args = array(
    ':user_id' => $data['user_id'],
    ':user_username' => $data['user_username'],
    ':user_password' => $data['user_password']
    );
$db->query($query, $args);


$query = "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_username = :username LIMIT 1";
$results = $db->query($query, array(':username' => $username));
```

Can someone help modify this code to allow this format?

I am also concerned about the new method. My current code allows for me to prepare a statement and bind some params and insert them, then bind some more and insert them without preparing the statement again. Would the new way I am wanting to change it to would kill that functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am making some minor comments on this now old question.

The way you have made your wrapper hard-codes your choices unnecessarily.

Observe your current constructor:

```
public function __construct($user, $pass, $dbname)
{
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $dbname;
    //$dsn = 'sqlite:myDatabase.sq3';
    //$dsn = 'sqlite::memory:';
    $options = array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
                );
    try {
        $this->_dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}
```

It is clear from your comments that you are already considering a different dsn.  You are needlessly locking PDO down to mysql localhost connections.  All of these settings **make your class less reusable**.

Catching and calling `exit` further locks your class down to self-destructing.  It gives no chance for someone to use your class, see that the database didn't connect catch the exception themselves and deal with it the way they want.

### What does your class need?

It needs a PDO object (that is all).  The rest of the class does not depend on all of the settings that you made in your constructor.

So, I would construct your PDO object outside of this class.  Your constructor then becomes:

```
public function __constructor(PDO $pdo)
{
    $this->_dbh = $pdo;
}
```

Flexibility and Reusability ensues.

Comment: also lets not forget Dependency Injection which is why your method Paul is better.

Answer (score 1):

I think adding a new method to your existing class and calling existing query,bind and execute methods should be enough:

```
public function query2($query,$params)    {        
    $this->query($query);    
    foreach($params as $k=>$v){
        $this->bind($k, $v);
    }
    return $this->execute();
}
```

Comment: binding inside foreach requires reference, you need to use &$v because once the foreach loop ends, $k, and $v not exist anymore...